# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: Strict stubbing argument mismatch: webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive()

Tags: mockito, junit5, soap-client

I am using soap client to make api call and try to mock the soap client in unit test and i get the stubbing argument mismatch

```
    public Respproxy updateId(final ReqProxy req) {
    Req request = createReq(req);
    Rpy response = (Rpy) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("www.example.com/path", request);
    return Respproxy.toBuilder().id(response.getId()).build();
}
 private Req createReq() {
    Req updateReq = new Req();
    updateReq.setDate(Localtime.now());
    return updateReq;
}
```

i tried

```
    @Test
void testUpdateId() {
    // Req mockReq = mock(Req.class);
    Rpy mockRpy = mock(Rpy.class);

    when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("null/UpdateId", mockReq())).thenReturn(mockRpy);
    updateIdSoapClient.updateId(Reqproxy.toBuilder.id(123));
   verify(webServiceTemplate, times(1)).marshalSendAndReceive(mockReq());
}

private Req mockReq() {
    Req updateReq = new Req();
    updateReq.setDate(Localtime.now());
    return updateReq;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 @InjectMocks
private UpdateIdSoapClient updateIdSoapClient;

@Mock
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<String> urlCaptor;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Req> requestCaptor;

   @Test
void testUpdateId() {

    when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(anyString(), any(Req.class))).thenReturn(updateRpy());
  //  when(webServiceTemplate.getDefaultUri()).thenReturn("www.example.com");

    Respproxy result = updateIdSoapClient.updateId(ReqProxy.tobuilder().id(123));

    verify(webServiceTemplate).marshalSendAndReceive(urlCaptor.capture(), requestCaptor.capture());

    assertEquals("www.example.com/path", urlCaptor.getValue());
    assertNotNull( requestCaptor.getValue().getDate());
}
```